# python - log the request's journey

Tags: python, debugging, stack-trace

I want to log all methods a single request has visited once at the end of the request for debugging purposes.

I'm ok with starting with just one class at first:

here is my desired output example:

```
logging full trace once
                      '__init__': ->
                                'init_method_1' ->
                                            'init_method_1_1' 
                                'init_method_2'
                      'main_function': ->
                                'first_main_function': ->
                                        'condition_method_3'
                                        'condition_method_5'
```

here is my partial attempt:

```
import types

class DecoMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        for attr_name, attr_value in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(attr_value, types.FunctionType):
                attrs[attr_name] = cls.deco(attr_value)

        return super(DecoMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    @classmethod
    def deco(cls, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            name = func.__name__
            stacktrace_full.setdefault(name, [])
            sorted_functions = stacktrace_full[name]
            if len(sorted_functions) > 0:
                stacktrace_full[name].append(name)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("after",func.__name__)
            return result
        return wrapper

class MyKlass(metaclass=DecoMeta):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Approaches

I think there are two different approaches worth considering for this problem:

1. "Simple" logging metaclass, or
2. Beefier metaclass to store call stacks

If you only need the method calls to be printed as they are made, and you don’t care about saving an actual record of the method call stack, then the first approach should do the trick.

I’m not certain which approach you’re looking for (if you had anything specific in mind), but if you know you need to store the method call stack, in addition to printing invocations, you might want to skip ahead to the second approach.

*Note: All code hereafter assumes the presence of the following imports:*

```py
from types import FunctionType
```

## 1. Simple Logging Metaclass

This approach is far easier, and it doesn’t require too much extra work on top of your first attempt (depending on special circumstances we want to account for). However, as already mentioned, this metaclass is solely concerned with logging. If you definitely need to save a method call stack structure, consider skipping ahead to the second approach.

### Changes to `DecoMeta.__new__`

With this approach, your `DecoMeta.__new__` method remains mostly unchanged. The most notable change made in the code below is the addition of the “_in_progress_calls” list to `namespace`. `DecoMeta.deco`’s `wrapper` function will use this attribute to keep track of how many methods have been invoked, but not ended. With that information, it can appropriately indent the printed method names.

Also note the inclusion of `staticmethod` to the `namespace` attributes we want to decorate via `DecoMeta.deco`. However, you may not need this functionality. On the other hand, you may want to consider going further by accounting for `classmethod` and others, as well.

One other change you’ll notice is the creation of the `cls` variable, which is modified directly before being returned. However, your existing loop through the namespace, followed by both the creation and return of the class object should still do the trick here.

### Changes to `DecoMeta.deco`

1. We set `in_progress_calls` to the current instance’s `_in_progress_calls` to be used later in `wrapper`
2. Next, we make a small modification to your first attempt to handle `staticmethod` — something you may or may not want, as mentioned earlier
3. In the “Log” section, we need to calculate `pad` for the following line, in which we print the `name` of the called method. After printing, we add the current method `name` to `in_progress_calls`, informing other methods of the in-progress method
4. In the “Invoke Method” section, we (optionally) handle `staticmethod` again.

   Aside from this minor change, we make one small but significant change by adding the `self` argument to our `func` call. Without this, the normal methods of the class using `DecoMeta` would start complaining about not being given the positional `self` argument, which is kind of a big deal, since `func.__call__` is a `method-wrapper` and needs the instance to which our method is bound.
5. The final change to your first attempt is to remove the last `in_progress_calls` value, since we have officially invoked the method and are returning `result`

### Shut Up, and Show Me the Code

```py
class DecoMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace):
        namespace["_in_progress_calls"] = []
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)

        for attr_name, attr_value in namespace.items():
            if isinstance(attr_value, (FunctionType, staticmethod)):
                setattr(cls, attr_name, mcs.deco(attr_value))
        return cls

    @classmethod
    def deco(mcs, func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            in_progress_calls = getattr(self, "_in_progress_calls")

            try:
                name = func.__name__
            except AttributeError:  # Resolve `staticmethod` names
                name = func.__func__.__name__

            #################### Log ####################
            pad = " " * (len(in_progress_calls) * 3)
            print(f"{pad}`{name}`")
            in_progress_calls.append(name)

            #################### Invoke Method ####################
            try:
                result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except TypeError:  # Properly invoke `staticmethod`-typed `func`
                result = func.__func__(*args, **kwargs)

            in_progress_calls.pop(-1)
            return result
        return wrapper
```

### What Does It Do?

Here’s some code for a dummy class that I tried to model after your desired example output:

**Setup**

*Don't pay too much attention to this block. It's just a silly class whose methods call other methods*

```py
class MyKlass(metaclass=DecoMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i_1()
        self.i_2()

    #################### Init Methods ####################
    def i_1(self):
        self.i_1_1()

    def i_1_1(self): ...
    def i_2(self): ...

    #################### Main Methods ####################
    def main(self, x):
        self.m_1(x)

    def m_1(self, x):
        if x == 0:
            self.c_1()
            self.c_2()
            self.c_4()
        elif x == 1:
            self.c_3()
            self.c_5()

    #################### Condition Methods ####################
    def c_1(self): ...
    def c_2(self): ...
    def c_3(self): ...
    def c_4(self): ...
    def c_5(self): ...
```

**Run**

```py
my_k = MyKlass()
my_k.main(1)
my_k.main(0)
```

**Console Output**

```
`__init__`
   `i_1`
      `i_1_1`
   `i_2`
`main`
   `m_1`
      `c_3`
      `c_5`
`main`
   `m_1`
      `c_1`
      `c_2`
      `c_4`
```

## 2. Beefy Metaclass to Store Call Stacks

Because I’m unsure whether you actually want this, and your question seems more focused on the metaclass part of the problem, rather than the call stack storage structure, I’ll focus on how to beef up the above metaclass to handle the required operations. Then, I’ll just make a few notes on the many ways you could store the call stack and “stub” out those parts of the code with a simple placeholder structure.

The obvious thing we need is a persistent call stack structure to extend the reach of the ephemeral `_in_progress_calls` attribute. So we can start by adding the following uncommented line to the top of `DecoMeta.__new__`:

```py
namespace["full_stack"] = dict()
# namespace["_in_progress_calls"] = []
# cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)
# ...
```

Unfortunately, the obviousness stops there, and things get tricky fairly quickly if you want to trace anything beyond very simple method call stacks.

Regarding how we need to save our call stack, there are a few things that might limit our options:

1. We can’t use a simple dict, with method names as keys, because in the resulting arbitrarily-complex call stack, it’s entirely possible that method X could call method Y multiple times
2. We can’t assume that every call to method X will invoke the same methods, as your example with “conditional” methods indicates. This means that we can’t say that any invocation of X will yield call stack Y, and neatly save that information somewhere
3. We need to limit the persistence of our new `full_stack` attribute, since we declare it on a class-wide basis in `DecoMeta.__new__`. If we don’t, then all instances of `MyKlass` will share the same `full_stack`, swiftly undermining its usefulness

Because the first two are highly dependent on your preferences/requirements and because I think your question is more concerned with the problem’s metaclass aspect, rather than call stack structure, I’ll start by addressing the third point.

To ensure each instance gets its own `full_stack`, we can add a new `DecoMeta.__call__` method, which gets called whenever we make an instance of `MyKlass` (or anything using `DecoMeta` as a metaclass). Just drop the following into `DecoMeta`:

```py
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    setattr(cls, "full_stack", dict())
    return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The last piece is to figure out how you want to structure `full_stack` and add the code to update it to the `DecoMeta.deco.wrapper` function.

A deeply-nested list of strings, naming the methods invoked in order, together with the methods invoked by those methods, and so on... should get the job done and sidestep the first two problems mentioned above, but that sounds messy, so I’ll let you decide if you actually need it.

As an example, we can make `full_stack` a dict with keys of `Tuple[str]`, and values of `List[str]`. Be warned that this will quietly fail under both of the aforementioned problem conditions; however, it does serve to illustrate the updates that would be necessary to `DecoMeta.deco.wrapper` should you decide to go further.

Only two lines need to be added:

First, immediately below the signature of `DecoMeta.deco.wrapper`, add the following uncommented line:

```py
full_stack = getattr(self, "full_stack")
# in_progress_calls = getattr(self, "_in_progress_calls")
# ...
```

Second, in the “Log” section, right after the `print` call, add the following uncommented line:

```py
# print(f"{pad}`{name}`")
full_stack.setdefault(tuple(in_progress_calls), []).append(name)
# in_progress_calls.append(name)
# ...
```

## TL;DR

If I am correct in interpreting your question as asking for a metaclass that really does just log method calls, then the first approach (outlined above under the “Simple Logging Metaclass” heading) should work great. However, if you also need to save a full record of all method calls, you can start by following the suggestions under the “Beefy Metaclass to Store Call Stacks” heading.

Please let me know if you have any other questions or clarifications. I hope this was useful!